# Most efficient way to produce dynamic table in PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a dynamic table below:

```
echo '<table border=1>';
echo '<tr align="center" width="140"><td>column 1 &rarr;
<br />&darr; column 2</td>';
echo "<td width='70'>{$c1}</td>";
echo "<td width='70'>{$c2}</td>";
echo "<td width='70'>{$c3}</td>";
echo "<td width='70'>{$c4}</td>";
echo "<td width='70'>{$c5}</td>";
echo '</tr>';
for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i+=5) {
    echo '<tr align="center">';
    echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>
    <td>'.$c1*$i.'</td>
    <td>'.$c2*$i.'</td>
    <td>'.$c3*$i.'</td>
    <td>'.$c4*$i.'</td>
    <td>'.$c5*$i.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

I was just wondering if there was a more effective less time-consuming method of generating it?

The table is created from the following inputs

```
min, max, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5
```

where if for example:

```
min=30, max=45, c1=5, c2=10, c3=15, c4=20, c5=25
```

the table might look something like:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a bit different approach. At first I don't like the idea of having calculations (even simple ones) and view/result/html code mixed. So I would separate those tasks. Normally in most bigger applications this kind of table generation would not even be possible (like MVC frameworks) or is at least not preferred. Also I moved out the styling of the table.

Next to that I don't like the numbered values, a list of data looks like an array. I have not enough meta information whether that's correct so I just made it an array since it looks to make sense. The amount of columns is flexible now also.

View code (so PHP) I always try to keep as compact as possible but readable. Mostly simple code, not many loops, not many different functions just basics. So not a for loop with a specific step because it is not relevant. The view part should just show the data as it gets the data.

```
<?PHP

//settings
$min=30;
$max=45;
$step=5;
$cols=array(5,10,15,20,25);

//result array
$data=array();

//data calculation
for($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i+=$step) {
    foreach($cols AS $col => $val) {
    $data[$i][$col]=$val*$i;

    }
}

//html generation
?>

<style type="text/css">
    th, td {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>
<table border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">column 1 &rarr;</th>
            <?PHP
                foreach($cols AS $val) {
                    echo '<th rowspan=2 scope="col">'.$val.'</th>';
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">&darr; column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?PHP foreach($data AS $i => $row) { ?>
            <tr scope="row">
                <td><?PHP echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?PHP echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?PHP } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope parts are useful for your project. Hope there are some. I like to write out quite lots of indents / tabs / newlines but you can always style the HTML as you want off course. Next to that I also always add table head, body and scopes which is different from your question but gives the same output in terms of layout off course as asked.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't `echo` the HTML, but simply populate a table with values from PHP. This makes it arguably more readable.

As for *less time consuming*, there's not really anything you can leave out, but then again, it only really takes a couple of minutes to hash it out.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><?php echo $c1 ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $c2 ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $c3 ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $c4 ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $c5 ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i+=5): ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c1 * $i ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c2 * $i ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c3 * $i ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c4 * $i ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c5 * $i ?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a quicker way of making tables. I would recommend, however, that if you are going to output that much HTML you exit out of PHP mode to clean things up. Maybe change this:

```
echo "<td width='70'>{$c1}</td>";
echo "<td width='70'>{$c2}</td>";
echo "<td width='70'>{$c3}</td>";
echo "<td width='70'>{$c4}</td>";
echo "<td width='70'>{$c5}</td>";
```

... into ...

```
<td width='70'><?=$c1?></td>
<td width='70'><?=$c2?></td>
<td width='70'><?=$c3?></td>
<td width='70'><?=$c4?></td>
<td width='70'><?=$c5?></td>
```